# How to output to the console in this form from tables (sql)?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to output to the console from tables in this form (sql):

```
| Monday | John (4.45 hours), Jane (7.54 hours), Alex (3.5 hours) |
```

`employee_id` with id first table connect foreign key::

```
| id | name |     
| 42 | John |     
| 43 | Jane |
```

2nd table:

```
| id | employee_id | hours |    date   |    
|  1 |      42     |  4.5  | 12/1/2020 |     
|  2 |      42     |  7.0  | 12/2/2020 |     
|  3 |      43     |  5.5  | 12/1/2020 |     
|  4 |      43     |  6.0  | 12/2/2020 |
```

Comment: How dod you try to obtain this output?

Comment: Type of date in 2nd table is date format for in varchar?

Comment: Your sample data does not match your expected output. What if you have dozens of employees? Do you truly want to list all their summaries in a single data field?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/api

Comment: And why are you posting the same question over and over again from different accounts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your date is stored as a varchar type then find below query.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(eh.date, '%c/%e/%Y'), '%W'), group_concat(e.name, ' (', x.total_hours, ' hours)' SEPARATOR  ', ') 
  from employee e
  inner join employee_hours eh on e.id=eh.employee_id
  inner join 
    (
      select employee_id, sum(hours) as total_hours 
        from employee_hours group by employee_id
    )x on x.employee_id=eh.employee_id
  group by eh.date;
```

And if your date is stored as date type then find below query

```
select DATE_FORMAT(eh.date, '%W'), group_concat(e.name, ' (', x.total_hours, ' hours)' SEPARATOR  ', ') 
  from employee e
  inner join employee_hours eh on e.id=eh.employee_id
  inner join 
    (
      select employee_id, sum(hours) as total_hours 
        from employee_hours group by employee_id
    )x on x.employee_id=eh.employee_id
  group by eh.date;
```

Hope this will give you the desired output.

Comment: @PinaColada Thanks for verifying my answer. please do upvote too.